# jQuery: Radio buttons not getting checked

Tags: jquery

I have a project where I am using radio button selection to change a class, easy stuff.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/bd7ujktx/13/)

This is my first time working with radio buttons with a script so what I can't work out is why the radio buttons aren't appearing checked/selected, I even added some jQuery to force them to be "checked" still with no luck.

```
$('input.eaBtn[type="radio"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data('class'))
    $('.eaStaff').removeClass('transBg darkBg lightBg customBg');
    $('.eaStaff').addClass($(this).data('class'));
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `e.preventDefault();`

This is the reason it is preventing the field to choose this option.

And after that, you dont need this line anymore `$(this).attr('checked', true);`

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bd7ujktx/15/)

**CODE:**

```
$('input.eaBtn[type="radio"]').click(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data('class'))
    $('.eaStaff').removeClass('transBg darkBg lightBg customBg');
    $('.eaStaff').addClass($(this).data('class'));
    //$(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, working answer with the fiddle wins, thanks to all the others with working answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
To make it checked
$('#radioId').attr('checked', true);

To make it unchecked
$('#radioId').attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `e.preventDefault();` from the click event.
2. Suggestion use change event
3. Also use `.prop()` for checking and un-checking instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `e.preventDefault();`  from the click event

Comment: this has been answered 2 times already i doubt answering it again will change a thing.. just saying

Comment: i typed before thy answerd when i submit i saw two answers already there is nothing wrong in that don't , u no need to inform , i know what i do @guradio